# Dynamics Crm 2013+ open custom activity throws "record unavailable" message - team does not exist

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have some cases where a user gets an 'record unavailable' error message when trying to open a custom activity. This does not happen with all records and in each case the user that is trying to open the record is the owner.

In the trace file the following error is appearing when this happens:

> Crm Exception: Message: team With Id = 97d71e7a-50c6-e211-93d3-0050569e39a0 Does Not Exist, ErrorCode: -2147220969

The above GUID, is actually the user id and not a team id, so I am not sure why CRM thinks it is a team. The owner fields in this record have the correct owner details and owneridtype is 8, which is systemuser.

A workaround we have found, is to assign the record to another user, then assign it back to the original owner. For some reason this fixes it. I have checked the record in the database before and after we apply the fix mentioned above and there are no obvious differences. The owner fields appear to be correct.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any custom plug-ins?

Comment: no plugins are registered for that entity.

Comment: Are there plugins with no primary entity (that respond to all entities)? What about plugins for other entities that may be affected as well when the user opens the custom activity? I would search all plugins source code for anything related to ownership changes etc.